# tables sum collation is latin1_swedish_ci, but all individual tables show utf8_general_ci

Tags: mysql, wordpress, collation

This MySQL db was set up in Godaddy from installing WordPress. Things on the site were acting glitchy - swapping out theme and deactivating plugins didn't help, so I decided to take a look at the tables using phpmyAdmin.

I've never seen this before - all tables use utf8_general_ci (there are 13 tables), but at the bottom is the summary of everything and the collation shows  latin1_swedish_ci, and not the utf8...

Seems like this shouldn't be.  What can I do to make it all uniform, using the utf8... and not the latin1_swedish?

Answer (score 1):

To help explain, `SHOW CREATE TABLE` gives you something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `h2u` (
  `c` varchar(9) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This says that the column `c` is utf8 (and some utf8 collation, probably utf8_general_ci), but the *default* for any other columns you might *add* is latin1 (and some latin1 collation, probably latin1_swedish_ci).

The `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` on the *column* is what matters.

(It is sad that 3rd party software, while trying to be helpful, sometimes obscures useful info.)

**Edit**

I would *guess* from the picture that the *default* for the *database* is latin1 / latin1_swedish_ci and the *default* for each *table* is utf8 / utf8_general_ci.  But the important thing is what the setting is for each *column*; the image does not show that.

The character set and collation for each column is important if you are using anything other than English text.  Are you?

Yes, you have observed something strange.  I am trying to say that it is probably not important, and very unlikely to cause any glitches other than with non-English text.

The following would have created output similar to the image:

```
CREATE DATABASE wp DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1;
CREATE TABLE wp_users (...) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8; -- overriding the 'latin1'
```

Comment: It's in the collation column.  Perhaps a photo would help?  Unless I'm totally not understanding your point (which is probable). http://imgur.com/a/otbf1

Comment: To answer your question - No, nothing other than English will be used. So the culprit is not the db.  But I've worked on many WP sites set up using the GoDaddy auto-set-up. I don't see this anomaly in the other databases for the other sites...which were also set up using the GD interface.

Comment: If only English, then "there is no problem".  That is, don't worry about the discrepancy, it won't have any impact.

Comment: Thanks much for your detailed explanations.